# ERROR: Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, prefix, precompiled-headers

I am developing an app for iPhone and iPad.

Suddenly I can't run my project because of this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/AkdemiaMacBookAir/Developer/iOS/ios-akdemia/ios-akdemia/ios-akdemia-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I was looking for in Stack Overflow and I actually checked out that my Prefix Header is correct.

[image: My xcode build settings]

And here is the file:

[image: folder and file in Finder]

I don't understand why xcode try to compile the pch from this path '/Users/AkdemiaMacBookAir/Developer/iOS/ios-akdemia/ios-akdemia/ios-akdemia-Prefix.pch' if I never told it that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This guy fixed it:

http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=F42D8239A330C321132944A&currentPage=3

This was his answer:

Click on the name of your project on the list of files/folders on the left in Xcode (at the very top of the list). Look at the "Targets" section on the left-hand side of the window to the right. Likely, there's two listed with the second being a "test" item. Right-click on that item and select "delete". Then try to run the project again. See screenshot below for a visual cue.

[image]

Comment: Is no necessary to delete it, open the "test" item find the Prefix Header and fix the path. Thank you @jalagrange